# How do I set the tabIndex for a Button at run time in WinForms?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a generic message box where we have a few panels in which we add controls at runtime.

Here in my form, I've already `pnlBottom` on which `pnlButtons` is there along with some other controls.

Now at run time I'm adding an `OK` button to `pnlButtons` which is there on `pnlBottom`. I'm not setting a `TabIndex` for any controls in the `Designer.vb` file.

I'm trying to keep the focus on the `OK` button using the code below, but it's not working.

```
For Each control As Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf (control) Is Panel Then
        Dim pnlBottons As Panel = CType(control, Panel)
        If pnlBottons.Name = "pnlBottom" Then
            For Each ctrl As Control In control.Controls
                Dim pnlButtons As Panel = CType(ctrl, Panel)
                If pnlButtons.Name = "pnlButtons" Then
                    For Each ctrlbtn As Control In ctrl.Controls
                        If TypeOf (ctrlbtn) Is Button Then
                            Dim textBox As Button = CType(ctrlbtn, Button)
                            textBox.Parent.Parent.TabIndex = 0
                            textBox.Parent.TabIndex = 0
                            textBox.TabIndex = 0
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Here I'm setting the TabIndex for `pnlBottom`, `pnlButtons` and `OK` button as 0.

Please suggest how to focus the `OK` button.

Comment: `If textBox.Text = "OK" Then textBox.Focus()`? (without those Parent and TabIndex)

Comment: This is not how TabIndex is supposed to work. TabIndex determines the order in which the controls are being accessed via tab key (from the lowest to the highest index, without specific first/last indices). To set the focus on a specific control at runtime you can rely on the Focus() method, as suggested in the previous comment.

Comment: I made a little tool for StackOverflow to easily **increase or decrease the indentation of code by 4 spaces**. [Here's the link](https://github.com/Drarig29/IndentCode) to use it.

Comment: textBox.Focus() is not setting the focus on my button control at run time.

so i thought that i can use tab index o(zero) to show the focus on OK button but it is not working.

Comment: What control has focus?

Comment: Place Your code in subroutine and, when You find control (in this case when textBox.Text = "OK"), focus control and exit sub. (for example: `If textBox.Text = "OK" Then : textBox.Focus() : Exit Sub : End If`).

Comment: now i used textBox.Select() and worked for me. :) thanks everyone.

Comment: Off topic but: The scale of indenting should show you, that the code urgently need refactoring!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the focus on a control during Form Load event using either of the following options. ([Ref: How to set the focus on a control when the form loads in Visual Basic .NET or in Visual Basic 2005](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/822493). The original link is broken, so use [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150328142333/http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/822493).)

**1- Control.Select Method**

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Mybase.Load
    Me.OKButton.Select()
End Sub
```

> Focus is a low-level method intended primarily for custom control
> authors. Instead, application programmers should use the Select method
> or the ActiveControl property for child controls, or the Activate
> method for forms.

---

**2- Form.ActiveControl Property**

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Mybase.Load
    Me.ActiveControl = Me.OKButton
End Sub
```

---

**3- Control.Focus Method**

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Mybase.Load
    Me.Show()
    Me.OKButton.Focus()
End Sub
```

The reason that we call Me.Show() is to set forms visible to true. according to:

> You can use the Control.Focus method in the Load event of the form to
> set the focus on a control only after the Visible property of the form
> is set to True.

---

In cases you can not use `Me.OKButton` you can find the control you want like this:

```
Dim control = Me.Controls.Find("OKButton", True).FirstOrDefault()
If Not control Is Nothing Then
    control.Select() 'or other stuff
End If
```